# Velocity of small oscillations

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, approximations, coupled-oscillators

We consider that the displacements about equilibrium are small, in small oscillation. Do we also tacitly assume that the velocity (rather, its magnitude) remains small as well?

In Goldstein, it's mentioned while calculating the $T$ function (Kinetic Energy) that the $m_{ij}$ terms in the expression of $$T=\frac{1}{2}m_{ij}\dot\eta_{i}\dot\eta_{j}$$ can be expanded as follows:

$$m_{ij}(q_{1},...q_{n})=m_{ij}(q_{1}^{o},...q_{n}^{o})+(\frac{\partial m_{ij}}{\partial q_{k}})^{o}\eta_{k}+...$$

Here the $q^{o}$'s represent equilibrium coordinates. Now, they say that since $T$ is already quadratic in the $\dot\eta$'s, we can neglect all terms in the expansion of $m_{ij}$ except the first term.

But doesn't this assume that the $\dot\eta$'s are all small, when it's never been explicitly assumed so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Kinetic energy is *always* quadratic (assuming we're not relativistic), but potential energy is *never* strictly quadratic.  In order to get a nearly quadratic potential, one has to restrict motion to small deviations around an equilibrium point.

**update after comment**

The expression for $T$ depends on $\dot\eta$, of course, but it also depends on $\eta$ through the coordinate dependence of the inertia tensor $m(q)$.  For a system of massive particles that we analyze using conventional coordinates, the inertia of the particles, their masses, does not change.  However, when expressed in generalized coordinates, the inertia *can* vary with coordinate.  However, in order to use a linearized formalism, we must have a kinetic energy that depends on $\dot\eta$ alone.  That is, the inertia must be constant.

In order to achieve this, we restrict the coordinates to a small region around the equilibrium point, a region over which the inertia doesn't change appreciably.   We do this by expanding $m(q)$ in a Taylor series expansion, keeping only the term that does not depend on $\eta$.  Notice that the expansion is an expansion in $\eta$, not $\dot\eta$, and terms linear (and above) in $\eta$ are dropped.  That is, it restricts validity to small $\eta$, not small $\dot\eta$  The expansion has nothing to say about $\dot\eta$.   I don't have Goldstein in front of me, but I suspect the next formula is $T=m_{ij}(q^0)\dot\eta_i \dot\eta_j$.  Constant inertia, and the development can continue in the "ordinary" fashion.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question. Even if the kinetic energy is quadratic, it is so in the velocities, and small deviations around equilibrium doesn't necessarily imply small velocities, isn't it so?

Comment: That's correct.   Small deviations around equilibrium do not imply small velocities.  But we never assumed that the velocities are small.  They can be large, without limit (until they become relativistic).

Comment: How then does it make sense to drop all the terms of the $m_{ij}$ expansion except the first term?

Comment: Ah.  I misread the formula given.  Let me check ...

Comment: Still no.  That's an expansion of the inertia tensor with respect to $\eta$, not $\dot{\eta}$.  Again, the truncation is valid when $\eta$ is small.  It says nothing about the size of $\dot{\eta}$.   It's requiring that the inertia doesn't change too much as the system moves from equilibrium.  In order to do that, the system has to remain close to equilibrium.

Comment: If you're talking about the expansion of T, it's definitely in terms of $\dot\eta$'s. I don't get your argument in that case.

Comment: I'll edit my post.

Comment: I get your argument but what Goldstein says specifically is "as (the expression of T) is already quadratic in the $\dot\eta$'s, the lowest non vanishing approximation to T is obtained by dropping all but the first term in the expansions of $m_{ij}$". So I don't understand what the quadratic nature in terms of the generalised velocity has got anything to do with the approximation for the inertia term.

Comment: I don't think it does.  I'm not sure what Goldstein means, but I would guess that he is saying:  "the only thing that we need to do in order get the KE in the form that we want is fix how the inertia tensor varies with $q$.  We don't need to do anything about $\dot\eta$ because it is already in the desired form"